# How to parse CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss...] date format

Tags: datetime, go

As we all know, date parsing in Go has it's quirks*.

However, I have now come up against needing to parse a datetime string in `CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss...]` to a valid date in Go.

This `CCYY` format is a format that seems to be ubiquitous in astronomy, essentially the CC is the current century, so although we're in 2022, the century is the 21st century, meaning the date in `CCYY` format would be 2122.

How do I parse a date string in this format, when we can't specify a coded layout?

Should I just parse in that format, and subtract one "century" e.g., `2106` becomes `2006` in the parsed datetime...?

Has anyone come up against this niche problem before?

*(I for one would never have been able to remember `January 2nd, 3:04:05 PM of 2006, UTC-0700` if it wasn't the exact time of my birth! I got lucky)

Comment: "the date in CCYY format would be 2122" Are you sure about this? Every reference I find on Google says that it would be 2022.  In other words, CCYY is the same as YYYY.

Comment: «Should I just parse in that format, and subtract one "century"» sounds legit to me, given the task. Doing that should be easy with `.AddDate(-100, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @Flimzy I think it should be ... no? Happy to be correct on this (it would make this scenario so much easier!).

Answer (score 2):

The [`time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time) package does not support parsing centuries. You have to handle it yourself.

Also note that a simple subtraction is not enough, as e.g. the 21st century takes place between January 1, 2001 and December 31, 2100 (the year may start with `20` or `21`). If the year ends with `00`, you do not have to subtract 100 years.

I would write a helper function to parse such dates:

```
func parse(s string) (t time.Time, err error) {
    t, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05[.000]", s)
    if err == nil && t.Year()%100 != 0 {
        t = t.AddDate(-100, 0, 0)
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(parse("2101-12-31T12:13:14[.123]"))
fmt.Println(parse("2122-10-29T12:13:14[.123]"))
fmt.Println(parse("2100-12-31T12:13:14[.123]"))
fmt.Println(parse("2201-12-31T12:13:14[.123]"))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uqgDeVSuIXq)):

```
2001-12-31 12:13:14.123 +0000 UTC <nil>
2022-10-29 12:13:14.123 +0000 UTC <nil>
2100-12-31 12:13:14.123 +0000 UTC <nil>
2101-12-31 12:13:14.123 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

As for remembering the layout's time:

January 2, 15:04:05, 2006 (zone: -0700) is a common order in the US, and in this representation parts are in increasing numerical order: January is month 1, 15 hour is 3PM, year 2006 is 6. So the ordinals are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.